# How to print each element of a list until a certain length Python

Tags: python, list, printing, element, string-length

How to print each element of my list to a defined length (5), so for example:

```
myList = ["abcdefgh", "ijklmnop"]
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
abcde
ijklm
```

I've tried this (printing dates from an excel sheet):

```
i = 2
x =0
while i < maxR:
    valuesItems =  wb0["C" + str(rowList[i])].value
    itemDate.append(valuesItems)
    print(len(itemDate[x]))
    i = i+1
    x = x+1
```

But this prints "19" multiple times (the length of each element, not the element itself)

Comment: The operation is called "slicing". This answer is in relation to slicing lists, but slicing strings as you're showing works the same way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6030926

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for element in myList:
    print(element[:5])
```